# HighCharts - display heart rate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm new to HighCharts. Is it possible to use it to make a heart rate indicator (e.g. 100 beats per minute). I'm wondering if it's possible to modify this to do a heart rate indicator: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

The odd thing about this example report is that the lines between the dots are not a straight line. I think for a hear rate indicator, it'll need to be straight?

Comment: Hm.. This is interesting.  Why would you want to graph a consistent heart?  If you had a baseline like, say, time between heart beats you cuold get a graph like that with troughs and crests (provided that not every heart beat beat at the same time, that is).

Comment: Just for illustration purposes. It's not mean to be accurate, it just needs to be representative.

Comment: I think a flat line graph would be the best then.

Comment: Do you have an example I can look at? Will it be animated?

Answer (score 1):

the example you have provided is a spline chart. In the same chart instead of spline use a line chart

```
type: 'line'
```

here is the example how it looks.  http://jsfiddle.net/zz7pB/

hope this is what you are looking for